# ASP.NET Core-2.2 asp-all-route-data not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

In ASP Core 2.1 (and earlier) this would generate the proper URL:

```
<a class="btn btn-checkin" asp-action="CheckIn" asp-all-route-data="parms">Check In</a>
```

Now in ASP.Net Core 2.2 it is not working.  My app uses areas (not sure if it matters).  If I manually type in my paramaters using `asp-route-id="@id"`, `asp-route-currentFilter="@filter"`, etc, it will work.

UPDATE:

If I modify this line in my startup.cs file:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

to just be:

```
services.AddMvc();
```

then it works.  I do not know why.  Obviously a version compatibility issue.

Any thoughts or ideas?

This is my first attempt at using .Net Core 2.2.  I did also notice previously in 2.1 my identity area worked and in 2.2 I had to change the controller/action part of the anchor tags to `asp-page="controller\action"`

I don't know if that is related to this issue.

Comment: What do you mean not working ?Could you show your `parms` and your CheckIn action parameters ? You could check [asp-all-route-data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2#asp-all-route-data) usage.I tried and it worked in asp.net core2.2

Comment: Did you use asp-route in conjuntion with asp-all-route-data? Is your app using areas?

Comment: I apply both ways to the view in Area then, it does redirect and pass the parameters to action.

Comment: I have answered this here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56524032/4453486