# Link tag helper not working in asp.net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, asp.net-core-2.2

My link tag helpers are no longer working properly after migrating to asp.net core 2.2.

```
 <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="MyAction" asp-route-id="@Id">Link</a>
```

This works fine when I set the compatibility version to 2.1, but produces an empty href when set to compatibility version 2.2.

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="">Link</a>
```

I followed the steps [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

```
 .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);  --> Works

 .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);  --> Doesn't work
```

Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <LangVersion>7.2</LangVersion>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sendgrid" Version="9.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Stripe.net" Version="22.8.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="UAParser" Version="3.1.36" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Data\Migrations\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Hmm this is really peculiar, it's obviously working for other people fine. What does your csproj file contain?

Comment: What html get's generated?

Comment: That Windows.Compatability package version looks dodgy, also could you show your _ViewImports

Comment: Why is Windows.Compatabilty verdion dodgy? Looks good to me. Latest release from Microsoft... https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility

Comment: I had to disable endpoint routing to get it to work:             
services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                config.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today on a new AspNet Core 2.2 Project created using the built in MVC Template. The tags were not generated in the HTML.

changing the following

`services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);`

to

`services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);`

Works and the tags are now rendered in the HTML, I done some digging and it looks as though this has been raised as an issue in **AspNetCore 2.2**. They mention it has been fixed in **AspNetCore 3.0.0-preview3**.

As mentioned here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5055 and here https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6471

If you need to use AspNetCore 2.2 then a temporary workaround, if viable is to ammend the following in your `Startup.cs` as mentioned on the issue raised.

`services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)`

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty new in this technology, and I had the same problem. After I added

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, MyNameSpace
```

in ViewImports.cshtml, as mentioned here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-2.2
everything was fine.

Comment: I think this answers if the Taghelper is not being detected at all in the Razor view, not if it is detected but does not function as expected using the built in tag helpers in 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

For all views Add this line on header of **_Layout.cshtmml**:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```